# WinUI 3 ListView Linked To Observablecollection contains layer classes derived from class canvas

Tags: c#, .net, canvas, datatemplate, winui-3

I want to create an application like photoshop main canvas which groups layer canvases,

a listview which displays the name of the layers and a visibility button via a datatemplate of each layer added to the main canvas.

I created the class layer derived from the class convas

```
public class Layer : Canvas
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

   public Layer(Canvas mainCanvas)  {   

      // Initialize layer properties 
      Name = "New Layer";
      IsVisible = true; 
      mainCanvas.Children.Add(this);  
  }
}
```

ListView Layers :

```
<StackPanelGrid.Row="1"Orientation="Vertical"> 
    <ListViewx:Name="listViewLayers"x:FieldEdit="public"Background="SeaGreen">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate x:DataType="Layer">
            <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=TowWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

ObservableCollection ocLayers :

```
ObservableCollection<Layer> ocLayers = new ObservableCollection<Layer>();  
             ocLayers.Add(new Layer(mainCanvas){Name="AAA"});
             ocLayers.Add(new Layer(mainCanvas){Name="BBB"});
             listViewLayers.ItemsSource = ocLayers;
```

```
with DataTemplate DataType="Canvas" and ObservableCollection<Canvas>
```

if i add simple canvas Object just for testing it works

```
and with DataTemplate DataType="Layer" and ObservableCollection<Layer>
```

if i add Layer Object execution hangs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your app is hangs but let mentioned that instead of "Layer is a Canvas", I suggest "Layer has a Canvas". See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

So, it'd be something like this:

```cs
public class Layer
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Canvas Canvas { get; }

    public Layer(Canvas canvas)
    {
        Canvas = canvas;
    }
}
```

And add layers like this:

```cs
private void AddLayerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int layerId = Layers.Count + 1;
    Layer newLayer = new(new Canvas())
    {
        Name = $"New Layer #{layerId}"
    };
    this.mainCanvas.Children.Add(newLayer.Canvas);
    Layers.Add(newLayer);
}
```

Comment: thank you Andrew KeepCoding I take this solution